# AngularJS: Pass Parameter through URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a AngularJS Application in different languages.

Now I want to preselect a language, when the user calls the site, with following string at the end:
/en, /de, ...

Is this even possible in AngularJS? I also can use some other syntax, if this is needed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you'll prob need to provide links/code though if you are looking for implementation suggestions

Comment: Thank you for your reply, atmd! That do you mean with links? I´m just looking for a way to "parse" the URL (read the params from URL) in a nice "AngularJS"-Way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to get something from the url to run logic on (i.e. /de in the url)
you can use the `$location` object

[Angular location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

If you are wanting dynamic urls so that things like /de, /fr, /es go to the same page/view, you'll need to use the `$route` object

[Angular routes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

Comment: Thank you very much. $location works perfectly fine: $location.path() contains the String "/de" when I call my site via domain/#/de - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With the limited amount I could understand from your question..

```
var app=angular.module("angularapp",['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        redirectTo: '/en'
    })
    .when('/:language',{
        //do something
    });
}]);
```

you can then get access to {"language":"en"} object